# Replace field on a CSV string stored in single column of SQL Table

Tags: t-sql

I have a table with single column as comma seperated string like :
|Column 1  |
| -------- |
| A,B,C    |
| B,C      |

I want to replace A with X, B with Y and C with Z like
|Column 1  |
| -------- |
| X,Y,Z    |
| Y,Z      |

I tried using below in my select clause

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('A',[Column 1],0) > 0 THEN REPLACE([Column 1], 'A','X')
 WHEN CHARINDEX('B',[Column 1],0) > 0 THEN REPLACE([Column 1], 'B','Y')
 WHEN CHARINDEX('C',[Column 1],0) > 0 THEN REPLACE([Column 1], 'C','Z')
 END
From Table1
```

but that only replace the first field and I am getting this which is not desired output.
|Column 1  |
| -------- |
| A,Y,Z    |
| B,Z      |

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `REPLACE` replaces *every* instance of a string within a string, not the first, what you're saying simple isn't true.`'REPLACE('A,B,C,B','B','Y')` would result in `'A,Y,C,Y'`. The *real* question, however, is why are you storing delimited data in your RDBMS? It breaks the fundament principles of good database design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the approach with the CASE. Once one of the CASES is true, it won't take in consideration the others.

Try this:

```
SELECT  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([Column 1], 'A','X'), 'B','Y'), 'C','Z')
FROM Table1
```